# NullReferenceException inside Couchbase client 3.0 during connection

Tags: c#, .net-core, couchbase, nullreferenceexception, .net-core-sdk

I am working on migration from .NET SDK 2.7 to .NET SDK 3.0. Couchbase server 6.0.
This code throws `NullReferenceException`. I can't understand what I am doing wrong. I can't put the exception call stack. The site tells me that I have too much code or exception should be marked as code.

```
var options = new ClusterOptions()
    .WithConnectionString("http://192.168.1.120:8091") //Node's IP
    .WithCredentials("User", "Password")
    .WithBuckets("SomeBucket");
var cluster = await Cluster.ConnectAsync(options);
```

Comment: Are you using 3.0 or 3.0.1? I believe there was an issue in 3.0.1 that might be related.

Comment: @MatthewGroves I tried both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a problem in SDK and it was fixed in 3.0.2. But right now I am getting the same error on getting buckets. So need to wait for the new SDK version again :-)

**Update**

Some more details u can get [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/nullrefereceexception-inside-couchbase-client-3-0-during-connection/26474/5).
Shortly. Remove the port and all will be more or less OK.